# How to record exceptions masked by finally block's exceptions in Java?

Tags: java, debugging, exception, finally

*Just a note*:
I **know** that in Java `finally` block should never throw exceptions, otherwise it's [very, very, very] bad practice. 
I **know** that I should use `try-catch` inside `finally` to  handle (e.g. log or ignore) all exceptions and prevent them from propagating. 
I **know** that Java 7's Throwable has `getSuppressed` method, but I target Java 5 & 6.

Problem: In Java, in `try-finally` if an exception (name it *A*) is thrown by `try` block, control reaches `finally` block (in case of no exception it reaches it also, but it's not interesting in this question). Then, if `finally` block throws an exception (name it *B*), exception *A* is suppressed, or masked/swallowed, and exception *B* is propagated to the caller.

Question: Can i somehow detect the situation when one exception is suppressed by another and log/record the first one? 
... I spent too much time reasoning why particular exception has been thrown and not knowing what has really happened.

Rationale: Often problematic `try-finally` blocks are coded in a library (today it was Hibernate), so I'm not able to modify them.

Solution constraints: As I noted at the beginning, possible solution should not relay on Java 7, but, on the other hand, does not need to be production grade (being such would be a bonus). AOP is an option here.

(Please don't post *trivial* answers like "use Java 7 for development":)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I think is that even with AOP you can not intercept the exception consumption process. With AOP you could capture, say, all of the exceptions that are created, but you can't know when they're consumed.

For example:

```
try {
    ...
} catch (Exception e) {
    log.boom("Ouchies happened here", e);
}
```

Not every exception is re-thrown.

However, at a certain level MOST exception ARE, eventually, thrown so that the caller can handled them.

So, given that you will likely "leak" exceptions anyway, the game is to try and find the "leaking" exceptions.

Using AOP you can while away each Exception as it is created (whether you can do this at the Exception level, or have to do it at the individual class level, I can't say -- not that familiar with AOP in practice in this case).

Once you're capturing exceptions as they are created, then you start wrapping method calls via AOP. When you do this, you can capture the exceptions being thrown by the method.

So, with a little work, you know when returning from a method a) which exceptions were created and b) which were thrown. If you walk the exception "caused by" tree of the returned exception from the method, you can throw these out of the "exceptions created by this method" list. The remainder are the leaks.

Ideally, after a little analysis, you'll be able to identify which ones are simply not thrown (but handled in some other way), and which ones are actually shadowed by your finally blocks.

It's imperfect, and most certainly I wouldn't use it in production (I'd simply have to put to much work in to all of the race condition around recording stuff and such. More work than I'd want to do for this kind of debugging, frankly). But it might give you the information you are looking for, especially when used sparingly across a small domain of classes.

Comment: If I intercept every method, would this make JVM run slow? I noticed that sometimes Eclipse's breakpoint slows down JVM by factor of 50 (JVM 1.6, decent Eclipse version)...

Comment: Obviously the intercept is going to have some cost to it, but it shouldn't cripple the system. But it's another reason to use it sparingly, and only for debugging. You don't have to have it on every method, just every entry point where you want to track exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

There's a JNI method named "ExceptionCheck()" which, not surprisingly, checks for a pending exception. You can call it in the middle of a native method to see if some prior call has thrown an exception  which is waiting around for the JNI method to return before it's actually thrown. I wonder if you could call a native method from finally, then tried to use ExceptionCheck to see if there's a pending exception, if that'd work. I have no idea whether it would but I'd say it's worth a try.

Comment: I can't modify `finally`. They are sealed in jar files. And there are plenty of them :)